# Gradle task :compileScala fails on missing value for zincClasspath

Tags: scala, gradle, debian

This is a follow up on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486489/gradle-scala-plugin-how-to-specify-zincclasspath). I have a small sample project in `gradle` involving a `scala` file which fails to build on my new machine (it used to work on the same hardware + `debian stretch`):

```
$ gradle build

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':compileScala'.
> No value has been specified for property 'zincClasspath'.
```

My `build.gradle` file is as follows:

```
version = 0.1

apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8'
}
```

My current gradle version is:

```
$ gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2012-12-21 00:00:00 UTC
Revision:     none

Groovy:       2.4.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on March 1 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
OS:           Linux 4.8.0-1-amd64 amd64
```

and my `scala` (and `scalac`) version is 2.11.8. and I am on `debian stretch`:

```
$ uname -a

Linux front 4.8.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.5-1 (2016-10-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I thought for a moment there was a missing dependency (a common source of failure) and checked to install any `gradle` package which may be relevant (such as `libgradle-plugins-java`) but this did not solve the issue.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: hit by the same problem. any news?

Comment: @MartinMonperrus no I haven't heard anything, very sorry :(

Comment: for some weird reason most package manager (in my case ubuntu apt) installs really old version of gradle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me this problem disappeared by switching to  newer gradle. Right now to 4.9:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version=4.9
```

And then use `./gradlew` (or `gradlew.bat`) instead of gradle.

(for the record I had this problem with gradle 2.10, which is default on Ubuntu 16.04)