# Gradle suddenly broke

Tags: scala, gradle

I haven't modified any build files (and even tried reverting code), but Gradle started crashing on this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':macros:compileScala'.
> No value has been specified for property 'zincClasspath'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskValidationException: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':macros:compileScala'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
```

I was writing tests and after one run it just stopped working. Any ideas why it happened and how to fix it?

PS: Search only returned https://stackoverflow.com/a/43085471/1017211 which didn't help and I don't see any reason to update Gradle since it was working nicely with current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried on Android Studio:

> File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...

and/or

> Tools > Android > Sync Projects with Gradle Files

You can also delete the `.gradle` folder, then rebuild the project...

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and running gradle only from console. I have tried `gradle clean` and deleting `.gradle` as suggested, but problem persists (same message about zincClasspath).

Comment: WT*? I launched `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew test` and it failed. I haven't changed anything, just killed gradle daemon (which I tried few times before, but it didn't have any effect) and launched `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew test` again. Now it's **working**. I don't get it, Gradle is some serious bad black magic...